# Is $\mathbb{C^2}$ a vector space with new multiplication defintion over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, vector-spaces

I am trying to disprove this question:

is $\mathbb{C^2}$ a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ with regular addition and multiplication defined as: for every $\mathbb{z,w \in C^2}$ and every $\mathbb{\lambda \in C}$, $\mathbb{\lambda *(z,w)=(\lambda \overline z, \overline \lambda w)}$ ?

I think this is not a vectoric space because Associative law over multiplication doesn't apply:

$\mathbb{\lambda\mu(z,w)=(\lambda\mu\overline z, \overline{\lambda\mu}w)}$

$\mathbb{\lambda(\mu(z,w))=\lambda(\mu\overline z, \overline{\mu}w)=(\lambda\mu\overline z, \lambda\overline{\mu}w)}$

which are not equal, however, I am a bit confused because the multiplication is defined as scalar multiplication, and for every scalar $\mathbb{\overline z =z}$, like $\mathbb{\overline 5 =5}$, so I will eventually get $\mathbb{\overline\lambda=\lambda}$ and then the associative law will apply.

I know the unitary law doesn't apply too, I just want to make sure what I am missing here. Thanks.

Comment: You could also note that $1\cdot (z,w)\neq(z,w)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's not a complex vector space, but you made an error in your computations. Yes, you have$$(\lambda\mu)(z,w)=\left(\lambda\mu\overline z,\overline\lambda\overline\mu w\right),$$but$$\lambda\bigl(\mu(z,w)\bigr)=\lambda\left(\mu\overline z,\overline\mu w\right)=\left(\lambda\overline\mu z,\overline\lambda\overline\mu w\right).$$And, yes, they are not equal, but you should provide an example. Take, for instance, $\lambda=z=1$, $\mu=i$ and any $w$ whatsoever.

Comment: I forgot its not normal multiplication afterwards, my fault. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad I could help.